# Get the language of user in android

Tags: android, localization

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/fwvde0wN3xcViMtADw6x

It seems that navigator.language property is always "en" in webview on androids. Then, what is the best way to get the language of user? Get it in native java code and pour it into webview by javascript? or any other better way?

Comment: Is this still the case? It seems I am getting the right code in the window.navigator.language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem is to set the user agent through the webview's settings:

```
WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUserAgentString(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
```

In your webcontent you then retrieve it through:

```
var userLang = navigator.userAgent;
```

This should only be used for a webview displaying local content.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to take the userAgent - `navigator.userAgent`, and run a regex on it looking for the language.

Example Android ua string (from http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/):

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0.1; en-us; Droid Build/ESD56) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17

so just match for the language: `navigator.userAgent.match(/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/)`, which returns `en-us`

If you want to be really safe, you can match for the presence of `Android 2.0.1;` immediately preceding the language. The regex for that would be:

`navigator.userAgent.match(/Android \d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}; [a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/).toString().match(/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}/)`

Comment: Newer versions of Android don't put language in the user agent string, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

this might help:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this directly in html file in webviews?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends where you need this information. If you need Android OS Locale, `Locale.getDefault()` would be just enough. For the server side, the best way to detect Locale is to read the contents of Accept-Language header of HTTP protocol.
In such case Locale detection depends on the server side technology used. For simple Servlet, you would just do `request.getLocale()`, for JSF you would read it from UIViewRoot, etc.

Comment: I just want to change language of html in webview. HTML is static and stored in local directory, so I can't use request header. hmmm.

Comment: For static HTML you can name files like something_de.html, something_en.html and so on and choose appropriate file at runtime.