# How to detect a "phone" language? (not browser but phone)

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have to build a localized application in JavaScript (jQuery Mobile, phonegap).
Each time I ask the language(navigator.language) it returns me "en" even when I set the phone language on French or Spanish.

How can I detect the phone language instead of the navigator language which don't seem to change accordingly to phones?

Comment: Although not detection, asking the user would be the safest bet.

Comment: It depends on the phone's OS; for example for Android, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device.

Comment: For Android, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547642/get-the-language-of-user-in-android I don't know if a similar problem occurs on other OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the user-agent will do the trick on android. I'll test the navigator.language on Ios (language reference is not in the ios user-agent :s). I hope it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detect the phone's language as far as I know. Using the user-agent or navigator.language are the only automated ways.

However, it is probably safest to just *ask* the user what language they speak.

Comment: I'd realy like to ask the user but this idea was rejected. but it works fine with userAgent + navigator.language if there is no userAgent for compatibility reason.