# How to detect user language with Forge?

Tags: trigger.io

The language detection [does not seem to be easy on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547642/get-the-language-of-user-in-android). I have not personally tested it yet but apparently, "navigator.language" always returns "en". iOS and Android can both return the current device language. Is there a Forge method to do that native/js bridge for us ?

Comment: It would be definitely a good addition to trigger.io forge toolset to have localization built in. Any *serious* app should be localized. We don't all live in the valley :-) (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code I used to achieve this.

```
if ( navigator && navigator.userAgent && ( lang = navigator.userAgent.match(/android.*\W(\w\w)-(\w\w)\W/i) ) ) {
    lang = lang[1];
}

if ( !lang && navigator ) {
    if (navigator.language) {
        lang = navigator.language;
    } else if ( navigator.browserLanguage ) {
        lang = navigator.browserLanguage;
    } else if ( navigator.systemLanguage ) {
        lang = navigator.systemLanguage;
    } else if ( navigator.userLanguage ) {
        lang = navigator.userLanguage;
    }
    lang = lang.substr( 0, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Forge API to detect language currently.

It's possible to work around the issue you point out though by using navigate.userAgent: see this question:

[Get the language of user in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547642/get-the-language-of-user-in-android)

Comment: do you plan to do something to simplify it soon? Just to know if I need to develop something solid or not. I prefer to trust Forge on this point especially since I do not know how Windows phones behaves on this point.

Comment: it's not currently on our near-term roadmap, but we'll triage our backlog next Thursday. We'll report back on this thread when we can be clearer on timescales

Comment: No timeline yet - we have to prioritize other tickets where there are no workarounds at present.